# I have property file at some loaction which consist of number of jar files names.Call from ANT and fectch all jar files at repository

Tags: ant, jar

I have a property files which consist of number of jar files in below format
`hellotest.jar=1.2.3`
`helootest1.jar=2.3.4`
`hello.jar=3.4.5`

first I need to change = sign to - in property file and then call this prpoerty file from ant
and copy that jar files from http://maven.tvl.com/nexus/udp/heloo/ to some particaluar location(/tmp)

Please let me know how can I do this by witting and target in ant(need for loop)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to build your own dependency management client. My advice is to use [Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) which already understands how to download from Maven repositories.

## Example

### build.xml

The ivy retrieve task can be used to download the project dependencies into a nominated location:

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="init" description="Resolve dependencies populate lib dir">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>
    </target>
```

### ivy.xml

This file list's your project dependencies. (Simpler than a collection of property files):

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="udp.heloo" name="hellotest"  rev="1.2.3" conf="default" />
        <dependency org="udp.heloo" name="helootest1" rev="2.3.4" conf="default" />
        <dependency org="udp.heloo" name="hello"      rev="3.4.5" conf="default" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Additionally dependencies have dependencies, so ivy will manage these for you as well.

### ivysettings.xml

This file controls where ivy downloads from. In this example two Maven repositories are configured, Maven Central and the Maven repo you listed as example above.

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="all-repos" />
  <resolvers>
      <chain name="all-repos">
          <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
          <ibiblio name="extra-repo" m2compatible="true" root="http://maven.tvl.com/nexus"/>
      </chain>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```